# Xml parsing terminates

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I tried to parse the following xml;

```
 <coupon>
  <MerchantName>Iwantoneofthose.com</MerchantName>
  <MerchantLink>www.redtagdeals.com/iwantoneofthose-coupons</MerchantLink>
   <Title>£5 Off on Orders £30+</Title>
    <CouponCode>5OFFOCT</CouponCode>
     <CouponLink>
         www.redtagdeals.com/online-coupons.php?coupon=1594262&afsrc=1
        </CouponLink>
        <Expirydate>2012-10-15</Expirydate>
       </coupon>
```

But the parsing terminates while encounter the character "£".

What will be the issue and how to resolve it.

thanks in advance

Comment: what code do you use and do you own xml itself ( can change it etc )

Comment: I am using saxparser for parsing the xml.  But the parsing terminates here <Title>£5 Off on Orders £30+</Title>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to parse xml having special characters,then you must have to use encoding.
i.e. at time of parsing xml instead of normal parsing use encoding as given below,

```
 InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
 is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
 Reader.parse(is);
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is meant by "Reader"

Comment: Check this link to know about reader   http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/character_stream_reader.shtml